# Type Error when running a large function in Python

Tags: python, csv, split

I am trying to run a large function that will process a large text file by splitting it up into a speaker and their speech, then further processing the speech into component paragraphs. Here is the code:

```
import os
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def driver(folder, input_filename, output_filename1, output_filename2):
    os.chdir(folder)
    with open(input_filename, 'r') as f:
        Hearing = f.read()
    hearing = BeautifulSoup(Hearing)
    hearing = hearing.get_text()
    hearing = hearing.split("RESPONSE TO WRITTEN")
    str (hearing)
    speakers = re.findall("\\n    Mr. [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n    Ms. [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n    Congressman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Congresswoman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Chairwoman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Chairman [A-Z][a-z]+\.", hearing)
    speakers = list(set(speakers))
    #print speakers
    position = []
    for speaker in speakers:
        x = hearing.find(speakers)
        position.append(x)
        def find_speaker(hearing, speakers):
            position = []
            for speaker in speakers:
                x = hearing.find(speaker)
                if x==-1:
                    x += 1000000
                position.append(x)
                first = min(position)
                name = speakers[position.index(min(position))]
            name_length = len(name)
            chunk = [name, hearing[0:first], hearing[first+name_length:]]
            #return chunk
            chunks = []
            #print hearing
            names = []
            while len(hearing)>10:
                chunk_try = find_speaker(hearing, speakers)
                hearing = chunk_try[2]
                chunks.append(chunk_try[1])
                names.append(chunk_try[0].strip())
                print len(hearing)#0
                chunks.append(hearing)
                chunks = chunks[1:]
                print len(names) 
                print len(chunks)
                data = zip(names, chunks)
                with open(output_filename1,'wb') as f:
                    w=csv.writer(f)
                    w.writerow(['Speaker','Speech'])
                    for row in data:
                        w.writerow(row)
                        paragraphs = str(chunks)
                        print (paragraphs)
                        Paragraphs = paragraphs.split("\\n")
                        data1 = zip(Paragraphs)
                        with open(output_filename2,'wb') as f:
                            w=csv.writer(f)
                            w.writerow(['Paragraphs'])
                            for row in data1:
                                w.writerow(row)
                                return True 
driver("C:/Users/Documents/Congressional Hearings/NHTF Project/Test Set", 'CHRG-107hhrg70750.htm', 'CHRG-107hhrg70750.csv', 'Paragraphs.csv')
```

However, when I run the driver function, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#159>", line 1, in <module>
    driver("C:/Users/mboogie/Documents/Congressional Hearings/NHTF Project/Test Set", 'CHRG-107hhrg70750.htm', 'CHRG-107hhrg70750.csv', 'Paragraphs.csv')
  File "<pyshell#158>", line 9, in driver
    speakers = re.findall("\\n    Mr. [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n    Ms. [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n    Congressman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Congresswoman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Chairwoman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Chairman [A-Z][a-z]+\.", hearing)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I thought this was referring to the file 'hearing' not bring a string, but when I tried str(hearing) it didn't resolve the error. I'm also confused about why its referring to three separate lines of code. Any suggestions would be appreciated - I've been stuck on this for quite a while!

Comment: What do you imagine "str(hearing)" to do?

Comment: It refers to three lines of code because that's what gets called; `<module>` calls `driver` on line 1, `driver` calls `re.findall()` on line 9, then `re.findall` attempts to `return _compile(...).findall(...)`, where the `TypeError` is raised. This is called a "traceback".

Comment: hearing is a list, from split, sometime just simply add a print hearing, will show you where the problem is. And str(hearing) help nothing, because its result was assigned to nobody.

Comment: This code is very difficult to follow, but I don't think nesting two `with open`s, both of which change `w` and `f`, will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got everything in one monolithic block of code, and it makes it much harder to test or modify. I've rewritten it as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import namedtuple
import csv
from itertools import tee, izip
import os, os.path
import re

DIR       = r'C:\Users\Documents\Congressional Hearings\NHTF Project\Test Set'
HARD_WRAP = re.compile(r'\n(?!    )')
SPEAKERS  = re.compile(r'^    (Mr.|Mrs.|Congressman|Congresswoman|Chairman|Chairwoman) ([a-zA-Z \-]{2,40})\.', re.MULTILINE)
NAME      = lambda m: '{0} {1}'.format(*m.groups())
Speaker   = namedtuple('Speaker', ['name', 'name_start', 'name_end'])

def load_hearing_response(fname, split_on='    Present:'):
    with open(fname, 'rU') as inf:
        html = inf.read()
    txt  = BeautifulSoup(html).get_text()
    return txt.rsplit(split_on, 1)[-1]     # return everything after last occurrence of split_on

def un_hard_wrap(txt, reg=HARD_WRAP):
    return reg.sub('', txt)

def pairwise(iterable):
    a,b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

def get_speeches(txt):
    speakers = [Speaker(NAME(sp), sp.start(), sp.end()) for sp in SPEAKERS.finditer(txt)]
    speakers.append(Speaker('', len(txt), None))    # tail sentinel for pairwise processing
    return [(this.name, txt[this.name_end:nxt.name_start]) for this,nxt in pairwise(speakers)]

def write_csv(fname, data, header=None):
    with open(fname, 'wb') as outf:
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf)
        if header is not None:
            out_csv.writerow(header)
        out_csv.writerows(data)

def main():
    # get text of Congressional hearing responses
    txt = load_hearing_response(os.path.join(DIR, 'CHRG-107hhrg70750.htm'))
    txt = un_hard_wrap(txt)
    # break into speeches
    speeches = get_speeches(txt)
    # write (speaker, speech) pairs to a .csv file
    write_csv(os.path.join(DIR, 'CHRG-107hhrg70750.csv'), speeches, ['Speaker', 'Speech'])
    # write paragraphs of speeches to a .csv file
    paragraphs = ([para.strip()] for speaker,speech in speeches for para in speech.split('\n') if para.strip())
    write_csv(os.path.join(DIR, 'Paragraphs.csv'), paragraphs, ['Paragraphs'])

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Note that this is untested, as I do not have the original data file.

**Edit:** After being pointed to [a sample data file](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CHRG-107hhrg70750/html/CHRG-107hhrg70750.htm) I made the following changes:

1. The text was been hard-wrapped; I added an `un_hard_wrap()` function to convert back to unwrapped text (each paragraph is followed by '\n').
2. I made an error in `get_speeches()`, using `sp.pos` in place of `sp.start()` and `sp.end_pos` in place of `sp.end()`. This is now fixed.
3. I tweaked the `SPEAKERS` regex to get rid of some false positives (ie a speaker says 'Mr. Speaker, I take offense to...' and it was detected as a speech by 'Mr. Speaker'.) This should now be solved - unless they start with a sentence under 40 characters long. If you know the longest possible speaker-last-name you could adjust the SPEAKERS regex appropriately, ie `{2,40}` could become `{2,26}` or whatever the appropriate maximum length is.
4. I added `... if para.strip()` to the `paragraphs` comprehension to strip out empty paragraphs.

Comment: This is much more elegant than what I originally had. I come up with this error - `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#145>", line 2, in <module>
    main()
  File "<pyshell#142>", line 5, in main
    speeches = get_speeches(txt)
  File "<pyshell#124>", line 4, in get_speeches
    return [(this.name, txt[this.name_end:nxt.name_start]) for this,nxt in pairwise(speeches)]
NameError: global name 'speeches' is not defined`

Comment: So close!! This works, but the .csv files created do not have the paragraph text. All i get is the speaker names in the first file and the column header `paragraph` in the second. Still loads helpful, since  this is the first time the process has actually been fully automated.

Comment: @MYR: if you send me the .htm file, I'll do some debugging - hugh_bothwell (at) hotmail (dot) com

Comment: @MYR: Changes made as above. Hope that helps! If you have any other issues, let me know :-)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!!! You have no idea how long I've been working on this - amazing answer!! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Your code structure is a little confusing, but I'll try to explain what is going on.

When you get to this line:

```
speakers = re.findall("\\n    Mr. [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n    Ms. [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n    Congressman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Congresswoman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Chairwoman [A-Z][a-z]+\.|\\n   Chairman [A-Z][a-z]+\.", hearing)
```

`hearing` is a list because you made it into one two lines above with `str.split`

```
hearing = hearing.split("RESPONSE TO WRITTEN")
```

Thus, you get an error because `re.findall` doesn't support a list as its second argument.  Instead, it requires a string or buffer.

---

Now, that is the problem.  The solution is to make the second argument of `re.findall` a string.  Where that string comes from though depends on what you want to do.

Judging by this line:

```
str (hearing)
```

I *think* you want to make the list `hearing` into a string representation of itself.  If so, then you need to reassign `hearing` like this:

```
hearing = str(hearing)
```

Comment: Thank you! This got rid of the error, but calling the function doesn't result in the needed 3 .csv files. Any ideas for debugging? I thought about breaking this up into three smaller functions - that might make it more manageable, but then I'd have to run through my 578 text files manually. I'm trying to automate the process with the function.

Comment: @MYR - No, don't break it up.  Instead, you should employ a coding help known as "stepping through the code".  Basically, build everything one piece at a time and only move on when that piece works perfectly.  Though it takes longer, doing this gives you greater protection against bugs and logic flaws.  For example, you would have noticed that your last for-loop will only run once since it has a return-statement in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
hearing = hearing.split("RESPONSE TO WRITTEN")
str (hearing)
```

`str.split()` returns a list of strings. When you then call `str()` to cast this back to a string, you don't assign the return to any name. Try:

```
hearing = str(hearing)
```

or, better, figure out which element of the list you split the string into you need, and pass that to `re.findall`.